# Reading two 8 bit registers into 12 bit value of an ADXL362 in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, bitwise-operators, bit

I'm querying an *ADXL362 Digital Output MEMS Accelerometer* for its axis data which it holds as two 8 bit registers which combine to give a 12 bit value and I'm trying to figure out how to combine those values. I've never been good at bitwise manipulation so any help would be greatly appreciated. I would imagine it is something like this:

```
number = Z_data_H << 8 | Z_data_L;
number  = (number & ~(1<<13)) | (0<<13);
number  = (number & ~(1<<14)) | (0<<14);
number  = (number & ~(1<<15)) | (0<<15);
number  = (number & ~(1<<16)) | (0<<16);
```

[ADXL362 data sheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL362.pdf) (page 26)

Z axis data register
[image: Z axis data register]

Comment: Your first line should be sufficient - from the "Z axis data register" section, _The sign extension bits (B[15:12], denoted as SX in the ZDATA_H bit map that follows) have the same value as the MSB (B11)._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line should be what you need:

```
int16_t number;
number = (Z_data_H << 8) | Z_data_L;
```

The sign-extension bits mean that you can read the value as if it was a 16-bit signed integer.  The *value* will simply never be outside the range of a 12-bit integer.  It's important that you leave those bits intact in order to handle negative values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do:

```
signed short number;

number = Z_data_H << 8 | Z_data_L;
```

The shift left by 8 bit combined with the lower bits you already
had figured out are combining the 2 bytes correctly. Just use the appropriate data size to have the C code recoginize the sign of the 12 bit number correctly.

Note that `short` not necessarily refers to a 16bit value, depending on your compiler and architecture - so, you might want to attempt to that.